# I'm trying to check if a server is up or not using Network Connection but seems like my parameters are not kicking in

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, server-side

What i am doing here is checking if the server network is up. for this instance i am checking on my localhost for this example which reason why i'm using 127.0.0.1 localhost and my computer user login and password login. but then observing the process it didn't accept the credentials even though i input it right already. please how do i do this right?

I already have tried placing them on '' or @'' I do it also in a double Quotes "" or @"" still did not work so I add like this one "\" or @"\" double black slash still don't work I run out of option on how since the document I used as a reference of the code showed that IP address should be use for the name of the server just adding a quotes and @ and \ will it did not work for me.

```
SIPrintServiceSettings _SIpss = new SIPrintServiceSettings();   
appConfig.GetSection("AppSettings").GetSection("PrintServeSettings").Bind(_SIpss); 
//AppSettings is a JSON File

                    //Set Configuration

                    remoteMachine = "127.0.0.1";
                    userName = "Administrator";
                    password = "12345";

                    using (new NetworkConnection(@remoteMachine, new NetworkCredential(@userName, @password)))
                    {
                        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(SysAppName, remoteMachine); if ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) || (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
                        {
                            //invoke slave here
                            executeProcessInformation();
                        }
                    }
```

I have this codes here on the NetworkConnection.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
/// <summary>
/// Represents a network connection along with authentication to a network share.
/// </summary>
public class NetworkConnection : IDisposable
{
    string _networkName;

    public NetworkConnection(string networkName,
        NetworkCredential credentials)
    {
        _networkName = networkName;

        var netResource = new NetResource()
        {
            Scope = ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = ResourceType.Disk,
            DisplayType = ResourceDisplaytype.Share,
            RemoteName = networkName
        };

        var userName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(credentials.Domain)
            ? credentials.UserName
            : string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", credentials.Domain, credentials.UserName);

        var result = WNetAddConnection2(
            netResource,
            credentials.Password,
            userName,
            0);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
        }
    }

    ~NetworkConnection()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(_networkName, 0, true);
    }

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource,
        string password, string username, int flags);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(string name, int flags,
        bool force);

}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
{
    public ResourceScope Scope;
    public ResourceType ResourceType;
    public ResourceDisplaytype DisplayType;
    public int Usage;
    public string LocalName;
    public string RemoteName;
    public string Comment;
    public string Provider;
}

public enum ResourceScope : int
{
    Connected = 1,
    GlobalNetwork,
    Remembered,
    Recent,
    Context
};

public enum ResourceType : int
{
    Any = 0,
    Disk = 1,
    Print = 2,
    Reserved = 8,
}

public enum ResourceDisplaytype : int
{
    Generic = 0x0,
    Domain = 0x01,
    Server = 0x02,
    Share = 0x03,
    File = 0x04,
    Group = 0x05,
    Network = 0x06,
    Root = 0x07,
    Shareadmin = 0x08,
    Directory = 0x09,
    Tree = 0x0a,
    Ndscontainer = 0x0b
}
```

Comment: There's no indication of why you'd need any escaping here at all.  Please put some time into editing your question to tell us what you're observing - it's hard to understand what you're trying to do and what's happening at the moment.

Comment: Done sir sorry i do not know the proper whay to ask question but i really need help on this which is why just tell me if i lack something about the question so i can make it clearly.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the database to see if working.  You first need to get SSMS working before you try to get c# working. The error messages in SSMS are better than c# and will errors will explain issue.

Comment: "but then observing the process it didn't accept the credentials" - what *exactly* did you observe? What happened? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions of how to write a good question.

Comment: this may help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: the database is already connected. the only things i need a server backup checking so thats why i create this function to check if server is up and if not then do a switch on server what back up ip add if its up something like that